# How do parallel wires attract if their force vectors point in the same direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-current

I don’t understand why parallel wires with current running in the same direction attract.
[image]

Wire 1 on the left, per the right hand rule, should cause wire 2 to experience a leftwards force. Wire 2 on the right, should cause wire 1 to experience a leftwards force as well. Shouldn’t they both be going to the left, never really meeting each other. When I think of attraction, I think of force vectors pointing inwards like so: —> <— , not pointing in the same direction like so: <— <—

What am I missing here? How do these two wires meet each other if they are both being pushed with equal forces (?) in the same direction. Does one wire exert a greater force than the other, all else being equal? If so, how could this be? When I watch video explanations of this problem, I typically see force vectors and magnetic field lines drawn out for *only one* of the two wires—this confuses me to no end.

I've spent several hours wrestling with this problem and would greatly appreciate some help untying this knot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be useful.  The $B$-field from wire 1 (on the left) points **into** the page of the diagram at the position of wire 2.  Conversely, the $B$-field from wire 2 points **out of** the page at the position of wire 1.  Since the currents are both going up as shown, the force on wire 1 is to the right, and the force on wire 2 is to the left.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! I just wasn't thinking of the field lines correctly.